# k-schemes determined by k-rational points

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Are $k$-schemes determined by their $k$-rational points? 
More precisely, if $X$ and $Y$ are $k$-schemes, such that $X(k)=Y(k)$. Is then automatically $X$ isomorphic to $Y$?

Comment: No. $k$-schemes may have no $k$-rational points. For example, $x^m+y^m+z^m=0$ in $\mathbb{P}^2_{\mathbb{R}}$ have no $\mathbb{R}$-rational points if $m$ is even. But, for different even $m$, they are not isomorphic.

Comment: @Mohan What if you strengthen the question sightly to demand not just equality but that there be a morphism of schemes that induces a homeomorphism on the $k$-rational points?

Comment: Not really. Let me call $X_m$ the curve above for a fixed $m$ (always even). We have a morphism $X_m\times X_n\to X_m$ inducing such an isomorphism (no real points), but clearly they are not isomorphic,

Comment: There are some special cases of this.  If $k$ is an infinite field, and $G$ is a connected, reductive group scheme over $k$, then the parabolic subgroups $P$ of $G$ are completely determined by their $k$-rational points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not in general.  For instance, let $K$ be any nontrivial field extension of $k$, $X=\emptyset$, and $Y=\operatorname{Spec}K$.  Then $X$ and $Y$ both have no $k$-points, so $X(k)$ and $Y(k)$ are the same, and this can even be induced by a morphism $X\to Y$.  But $X$ and $Y$ are not isomorphic.